# Finding Alternative for Triplets in a String Sequence

Tags: python, string, dictionary, encryption, alignment

There are two string sequences: 1 - main string: regardless of the length, it can be divided to sets of complete triplets. This sequence comes with a dictionary containing keys that are different triplets and values that are number represented as string. Triplets with the same value are alternatives of each other.

```
alternatives = {"atr": "1", "atx": "1",
                "erf": "2", "erg": "2", "erl": "2",
                "ghe": "3", "gaz": "3",
                "bnv": "4", "bnn": "4"}

main = "atrerfghebnv"
```

2 - user_input string: shorter than the main string and does not come in form of triplets necessarily.

```
user_input = "fgheb"
```

Task:

1 - See if user_input is a substring of the main sequence.

2 - If so, we need to find out which triplets it aligns to. In this example it aligns with three triplets:

```
main       = atr erf ghe bnv
user_input =       f ghe b
```

3 - For any triplet that the user_input aligns to, we should replace it with one of alternatives (some has more than one alternative) and then return the modified main string. In this example it should be something like this:

```
modified_main = "atrerggazbnn"
or
modified_main = "atrerlgazbnn"
```

There are two possibilities because there are two alternatives for 'erf'. It is not required to find all the possible forms. One is enough. But i have been working on it for a few days, and i can not get anywhere. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the problem you faced?

Comment: @Prasad Darshana
After three days, i still can not find a solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it on my own!

1 - Make triplet sets of the main sequence

2 - Detect to which set the user_input aligns with

3 - Find the alternatives for those sets in the dictionary

4 - add the new sets to the list and remove the old ones

5 - join the sets to reconstruct the new main sequence

```
from random import choice
alternatives = {"atr": "1", "atx": "1",
            "erf": "2", "erg": "2", "erl": "2",
            "ghe": "3", "gaz": "3",
            "bnv": "4", "bnn": "4"}

main = "atrerfghebnv"
user_input = "fgheb"

start = main.find(user_input)
length = len(user_input) - 1
main_triplet = [main[i: i + 3] for i in range(0, len(main), 3)]
align_pairs = [x for x in range(start, start + length + 1)]  

pairs = []

for nuc in align_pairs:
    y = nuc / 3
    if y.is_integer() == True:
        pairs.append(int(y - 1))

    else:
        pairs.append(int(y))

pairs = list(set(pairs)) 

for pair in pairs:
    triplet = main_triplet[pair]
    value = alternatives[triplet]
    other_codons = [k for k, v in alternatives.items() if v == value and k != triplet]
final_codon = choice(other_codons)
main_triplet.insert(pair, final_codon)
main_triplet.pop(pair + 1)
    
final = "".join(main_triplet)
print(final)
```